# Implementing a basic interpreter - should I learn regular expressions?

Tags: design, regular-expressions, interpreters

For fun and for practice, I'm thinking of maybe implementing a very basic programming language to run on a simple interpreter written in Java.

My question is this:

**Is it a 'must' to know regular expressions when designing an interpreter, for parsing the text?** Should I learn this topic before starting to implement the interpreter?

Or is it enough to just run through the text, break down into strings, etc, i.e. do 'basic parsing' without regular expressions?

Comment: How basic are we talking? `1+1` or `for(i=0; i < 5; i++) puts i`?

Comment: @delnan Not sure I understand the question, but basically the language is going to look something like this (imagine a new row every semicolon): `var x = 2; var y = x * 4; print y;` Very simple. Is it a good idea to learn about regex?

Comment: You should *never* parse a non-regular language with regular expressions. *Never*. You can only parse a regular language with regular expressions. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy

Comment: OTOH current regexes (most implementations, e.g. PCRE) are much more powerful than regular expressions.

Comment: @Kos, somewhat more powerful than the regular grammars, yes, but yet, totally unsuitable for *parsing* anything.

Comment: @SK-logic Agreed that there's a better tool for the job, but it's nice to remember that you can as much as *match* a context free language with regexes. About parsing - I don't know TBH. Brain food: http://nikic.github.io/2012/06/15/The-true-power-of-regular-expressions.html + http://regex.alf.nu/

Comment: You should learn regular expressions whether or not you plan to write an interpreter.

Answer (score 5):

The actual parsing usually wouldn't be done with regular expressions, or with code that is equivalent to some regular expression. You'd use them for lexing, i.e. for identifying numbers, variable names, punctuation, keywords, and so on without parsing them any further.

It's not required to actually *use* regular expressions in a lexer. But they are a very useful tool for describing and visualizing the syntax. Moreover, as regular expressions are basically very primitive parsers, learning the concepts surrounding them (e.g. repetition and choice) will benefit you when you turn towards parsing, since some parsing concepts are analogous to (though broader than) regex concepts.

There's also the fact that you can use regular expressions for many tasks beyond lexing; many common string processing tasks can be solved easily using them. So, in summary: You may be able to do without, but it's recommended. You don't necessarily need to learn *beforehand* though, you can try learning them as you implement the lexer.

Comment: Do you mean that regexes save me *some* parsing, by giving me an easier way to identify variable names etc. instead of doing a lot of parsing?

Comment: Yes. Regexes save you long sequences of "if the next character is like that, try this next" just to say, for example, that an identifier is a sequence of letters and digits. You can (and should, regardless of whether you use regexes or not) still put this code in a separate lexer to separate the parser from those concerns. But it'll still be the same amount of code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should not use *Regular Expressions* until you get to the point -- in your lexer or parser, where you can only deal with *Type-3* of [Chomsky hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy).

As [@Sk-logic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/237175/implementing-a-basic-interpreter-should-i-learn-regular-expressions#comment475431_237175) mentioned in the comments, parsing a non-regular language with regular expressions wouldn't work, simply because of the lack of recursive-ness in regular expressions -- in my opinion.

Parsing something like *CSS Selectors* could be a good fit for regular expressions, however working on anything above the Type-3 would get you in trouble at some point, I'd say.